# activeSelf return true and gameobject is false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have gameobject called `menuView`. I created script that `toogleGameobject` and it is simple - check if it is `selfActive`, if it is then set to false and if it false then set it to true. Problem is that for some reason it was not working. Then inside that function i set `Debug.Log(selfActive)` and in my console it returns that it is true but my gameobject is false.

Here is image:
[image]

I am calling script by button and script need parameter `gameObject` so I assign it through inspector.

```
public void toogleGameObject(GameObject gameobject)
{
    Debug.Log(gameobject + " " + gameObject.activeSelf);

    //In image above this down was under comment, so only Debug.Log was caled with function
    if(gameObject.activeSelf == true)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Here i assign and call gameobject:[image]

Comment: If you want some help, you will have to provide more code. We will need the code used to toggle the gameobject and the listener you've attached to the button. Maybe, the `Debug.Log` has been placed **before** you toggle the gameobject state.

Comment: @Hellium i edited it. I also noted that in image above this down was under comment, so only Debug.Log was caled with function

Comment: It is important, from where you call toogleGameObject and how you refer MenuView to it? can you share this code too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful how you name your variables. There is a local variable inherited from `MonoBehaviour` and `Component` named "`gameObject`".

You use that `gameObject` to refer to the GameObject that this script is attached to.

*That GameObject the script is attached to is what you are currently toggling on/ff **not** the one that is passed to the `toogleGameObject` function.*

The GameObject that is passed to the toogleGameObject function is named `gameobject` not `gameObject`.The *O* is not capitalized.

```
public void toogleGameObject(GameObject gameobject)
{
    Debug.Log(gameobject + " " + gameobject.activeSelf);

    //In image above this down was under comment, so only Debug.Log was caled with function
    if(gameobject.activeSelf == true)
    {
        gameobject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        gameobject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

You can also simplify this to:

```
public void toogleGameObject(GameObject gameobject)
{
    Debug.Log(gameobject + " " + gameobject.activeSelf);
    gameobject.SetActive(!gameobject.activeSelf);
}
```

---

Finally, I suggest you rename the parameter variable  `GameObject gameobject` to `GameObject objToToggle` so that you won't make this mistake in the future again.

```
public void toogleGameObject(GameObject objToToggle)
{
    Debug.Log(objToToggle + " " + objToToggle.activeSelf);
    objToToggle.SetActive(!objToToggle.activeSelf);
}
```

Comment: This isn't true. Even if you are right about "gameObject" is bad naming because base class has also a variable named gameObject, this code doesn't call it. It always calls variable in the closest scope. In this code it isn't base class's variable. it is the parameter of function.
You can even see this on log. Log printed gameObject as MenuView.

Comment: @Cenkisabi : Check the Debug.Log : `gameobject + " " + gameObject.activeSelf` you see that the first has a lower case `o` (referencing the parameter) while the other as a capitalized `O` (referencing the gameobject the script is attached to)

Comment: @Cenkisabi I don't think you understand my answer. I suggest you read it again before rushing to down-voting. The `toogleGameObject` function is meant to operate on the  GameObject(`gameobject` variable) that is passed to it as a parameter but OP's original code is modifying the GameObject the script is attached to because OP is using `gameObject` instead of `gameobject` in that function. Basically, that function parameter is now useless since it's not being used if you pass any GameObject to it, the function won't work on that GameObject but instead will work on

Comment: that GameObject the script is attached to. The reason it is printing "MenuView" GameObject is very likely because the script is attached to that GameObject so `gameObject` refers to that. *I am too tired for an argument but take your time to read OP's code then carefully read the answer I left.*

Comment: so sorry, you are right. I think I should take one more cup of tea to wake up. @Programmer pls make a small edit on your answer, I cannot remove my vote.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I renamed parameter to `go` and it is working now. @Programmer thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As I expected, you call `Debug.Log` **before** toggling your gameobject, thus, the Debug.Log tells you the opposite state of your gameobject (since you change its state right after).

```
public void toogleGameObject(GameObject gameobject)
{
    //Debug.Log("Before toggle : " + gameobject + " " + gameobject.activeSelf);

    gameobject.SetActive(!gameobject.activeSelf);

    Debug.Log("After toggle : " + gameobject + " " + gameobject.activeSelf);
}
```

Comment: At start of my scene i disable that object, and i set function to only debug.log line (no change of setactive) and it displays result on image. In Hierarchy you can see it is disabled but debug log says it is active

Comment: Then I guess @Programmer's answer is the good one, you have messed up the names of the variables (`gameobject` != `gameObject`)