# Interacting with objects from different Scenes Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good afternoon! I've made a main menu in which you create your RPG character, in this menu I can take values from input fields/buttons that add/substract values from attributes, etc. Everything is stored within a class called CustomCharacterSheet, now this object has a DontDestroyOnLoad script that allows it to be moved into the next scene which is the first level.

In my playerbehavior class I have a method that takes a CustomCharacterSheet object and reads its values and then creates a character with the appropiate values, the problem is that when I want to use the method to generate the character on the Awake() within the playerbehavior, the method requires an object of type CustomCharacterSheet in order to be executed, but how do I tell this method that the CustomCharacterSheet that came from the main menu is the one that has to be read? I tried GameObject.Find(); but it will tell me it cant cast a GameObject to a CustomCharacterSheet class.

Here is the dummy code:

```
CustomCharacterSheetClass {
//Values, this was created into an object in the main menu with a DontDestroyOnLoad() script to be moved into the 1st Scene
}


PlayerBehavior Class {

private void generatePlayer(CustomCharacterSheet cs){
//Do Stuff, this method requires the CCS in order to pull data from it and generate the player
}

void Awake(){
generatePlayer();//This is inside the playerBehavior class and needs to reach the CustomCharacterClass created in the main menu that was later moved to the 1st Scene
}

}
```

Comment: Everybody here can read code. Please provide us with some

Comment: There you have the dummy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GameObject.Find` is made to find a certain gameObject by name not for finding a script.

Since you said that script was attached to a gameObject, what you need to do is call `GameObject.Find("ObjectName")` with the name of that object and then you can access the script `CustomCharacterSheet` with `GetComponent`

```
public class GetComponentGenericExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject gObject = GameObject.Find("ObjectName")
        CustomCharacterSheet ccSheet = gObject.GetComponent<CustomCharacterSheet>();
    }
}
```

[GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) allows you to access any component of a GameObject.

Comment: Thanks a lot, figured it out earlier but still giving you a Check mark for being helpful! cheers!

Comment: @CNuts don't name a variable `gameObject` because that is already declared when you inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.  You will run into problems such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692651/3785314).

Comment: @Programmer oh yes you're right. I completely forgot about that, thanks.